# How do I remove the price meta data from a product/list page?

Tags: meta-tags

How do I remove the price metadata from a product/list page? For example, I have this on the product page:

```
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="100.75">
```

I want to remove it completely.
I'm running Magento 2.3.6

Answer (score 1):

See `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml`

You can overwrite this file in your custom theme or remove block `opengraph.general` with layout

References:

- [Create a new storefront theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
- [Templates basic concepts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html)
- [Product layouts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/product-layouts.html)
- [Layout instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Comment: I added the override here. Works great! Thanks!
app/design/frontend/../../Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml